# Spring Batch: Logs not written in log file in AfterJob Method

Tags: java, spring, log4j, spring-batch

I'm facing a problem with the logs when I'm launching  the Job on Unix, actually the log file contains all the informations except those that I write in the log in a JobExecutionListener and exactly in the AfterJob Method. 
When I'm using Eclipse I can see the report lines in the console.

Here is the configuration of log4j

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">


    <appender name="appenderConsole" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-6p [%-25c{1}] %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>



    <appender name="traceDefaultAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="log.tmp"/>
        <param name="encoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-6p [%-25c{1}] %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <appender name="reportDefaultAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="log.tmp"/>
        <param name="encoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
        <param name="threshold" value="REPORT#com.cegedimactiv.fwb.core.business.log.LevelReport"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="defaultLogger">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="traceDefaultAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="reportDefaultAppender" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="appenderConsole" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Is it writing to tomcat console log? spring batch by default uses log4j

Comment: Yes on the console I can see every information, another thing is that Exceptions are not logged in the log file also.